# Does MySQL support partial rollup like oracle?

Tags: mysql, oracle

As oracle doc says it supports partial rollup:

> Partial Rollup
> You can also roll up so that only some of the sub-totals will be included. This partial rollup uses the following syntax:
>
> GROUP BY expr1, ROLLUP(expr2, expr3);
>
> In this case, the GROUP BY clause creates subtotals at (2+1=3) aggregation levels. That is, at level (expr1, expr2, expr3), (expr1, expr2), and (expr1).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/aggreg.htm#DWHSG8612

Does MySQL support this?

I tried to search in MySQL doc and can't find any clue.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql documentation on [with rollup clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) is quite clear: you cannot provide a list of columns to the rollup clause to indicate what levels you want the summaries to be performed.

What you can do is to have the query with the rollup clause in a subquery and in the outer query you can remove those aggregate rows that you do not need (or you can do this in the client application). You cannot do this in the having clause, since

> Because the NULL values in the super-aggregate rows are placed into
>   the result set at such a late stage in query processing, you cannot
>   test them as NULL values within the query itself. For example, you
>   cannot add HAVING product IS NULL to the query to eliminate from the
>   output all but the super-aggregate rows.
>
> On the other hand, the NULL values do appear as NULL on the client
>   side and can be tested as such using any MySQL client programming
>   interface.

Comment: The linked documentation has been updated and now reads `For example, you cannot add WHERE product IS NULL to the query to eliminate from the output all but the super-aggregate rows`. `HAVING` seems to work.